# Google Analytics: How to check if new session is started

Tags: android, google-analytics

I changed my tracker from **EasyTracker** to v4 **GoogleAnalytics** without any xml configuration change, as a result i got a huge increase in the session count when i pushed new release to the store which resulted in drastic decline in other average reports. Any clue?

Without the analytic report, How can i know when a new session is started?

I am not using Application class to initialize the tracker object, i have made  the tracker  a singleton object, its initialized when its null, otherwise not. Each time i am going to trak event/action, i call initializeTracker(ctx)  and then track the view or action.

```
public static void initializeTracker(Context context) {
    if (tracker == null) {
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.ERROR);
        tracker = analytics.newTracker("XX-XXXXXX-XX");
        tracker.setAnonymizeIp(true);
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false); // tracking manually
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public static void trackView(Context context, String viewName) {
    initializeTracker(context);
    tracker.setScreenName(viewName);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}
```

Do you see any problem in this implimentation?

Comment: you can see history to checkout the sessions in google console

Comment: Thank you for the response, but is there any other way except checking from the google console?

Comment: Did the number of active users changed as well or only the session counts (end everything that depends on session)?

Comment: Onlly the session count. I had to revert back to v2 due to this session issue, recently i integrated v4 and result is same, session count is drastically increased.

Comment: @djabi i have updated my question with some code, please review if you can find something fishy.